# Symfony2 - Using old external library without namespaces

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.5

Let me preface this by saying that I am normally not a PHP developer, and am a complete beginner when it comes to Symfony2. I was kind of thrown into this project, and we are on a pretty tight deadline.

With that out of the way, here is my problem:

At my company, we have a PHP library for an internal API which is old; it doesn't use namespaces and it doesn't really follow any standard naming convention such as PSR-0 or PEAR. However, I need to use this in our Symfony2 project. Symfony2 obviously relies on namespaces a lot. Am I completely screwed if I don't update the library to follow the "new" conventions, or can I somehow use it anyway? The thing is, it is a pretty huge library, and we simply don't have time to do that right now (someone should have done it ages ago, but that is another topic...).

Theoretically, could I just place the lib under vendor/ and use good old old requires/includes in my bundles? Will this even work? Will I get a mob of angry Symfony/PHP developers after me by doing this?

Or, is there a better way that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Perfectly okay to do what you suggested. One of the core Symfony 2 framework libraries (Twig) is not namespaced.  The only thing is that if your library has classes then you need to use \ClassName to refer to them.  Here is an example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: And if the library only has a few public facing entities then you might want to write a Symfony 2 bundle to act as an interface.  That will make your application look modern.  But it is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you suggested, and you can even use the [`MapClassLoader`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/map_class_loader.html), and give it a static map between your classes and your files, so that you don't even need to require files from your library. You don't have to write this map by hand, [you can generate it with the class map generator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/class_map_generator.html)

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising.